# dev_err() function definition

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

I can see that `dev_*()` family of functions such as `dev_err()` are given as prototype in `include/linux/device.h`, but no where I could find its definition. I have visited sites like lxr.free-electrons, but without success. Used tags in the source code of linux kernel, even then failed.

What I am trying to find is how the  `dev_err(const struct device *dev, const char *fmt, ...)` is able to get the device information such as pci bus, etc from just giving `const struct device *dev` as argument to print in logs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Description of the device is constructed in function `create_syslog_header`, defined in [drivers/base/core.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.18.140/source/drivers/base/core.c#L2002). The function just extracts some fields from `struct device` object, and emits them via `snprintf()` into the string.

The function `dev_err` is implemented via `define_dev_printk_level` macro in the same file (`drivers/base/core.c`).